# Unshelve changes in TFS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I read some articles but my English isn't too sharp and I am still confused.

I have shelved changes. Is it possible to restore these changes in local repository?

I found my shelve changes and opened. Than I have two checkboxes:
a) Restore work items and check-in notes;
b) Preserve shelveset on the server.

If I press "Unshelve" what will happen? Restore changes? What is the purpose of these checkboxes?

Comment: This seems to explain it pretty well... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
a) Restore work items and check-in notes;
```

When you shelve the changes it is similar to doing a Check in, by that you can shelve your files and tag workitems and add the check-in notes that you would use if you were doing a check-in. so the shelveset will be created and any comments you have added and any work items you have linked will be stored with the shelveset. when you then unshelve, the files will be brought back to your local workspace and associated work items and comments will be prefilled in the pending changes window

```
b) Preserve shelveset on the server.
```

when you choose this option the files will be restored to your workspace, but the shelveset will remain on the server. by ticking this box you can unshelve the changes and make changes to the files, should you decide that the changes yyou have made are not required, you can then undo the pending changes and again restore the same shelveset as it was retained on the server.